# Does "so that" need modals?

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs

When I use the structure **so that**, must I always use the modals **can** / **could** / **won't** / **wouldn't**? Check the numbers 2, 4 below.

> 1) I wore warm clothes so that I **wouldn't** *be* cold.
>
> 2*) I wore warm clothes so that I *am/was* not cold.
>
> 3) Please arrive early so that we **can** *start* our meeting on time.
>
> 4*) Please arrive early so that we *start* our meeting on time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to use modals, though they are very common following **so that**. We use modals with **so that** because we are expressing the **intended** outcome (which may or may not have been the actual outcome).

However, here are a few examples of sentences that don't require modals, so hopefully you can see how natural they also look.

> > I put the rest in the fridge so that it doesn't go to waste.
> >
> > Pay him a compliment so that he gives you one back.
> >
> > Duck so that they don't see us!

*Note that each of the above examples needs little modification to also be able to take a modal, which demonstrates that though the greater use of **so that** is with modals, we can still use the phrase without them.

Comment: what do you think of my examples without modals?

Comment: They sound perfect as they are with the modals. The first sentence works fine without, but the second one sounds false when you don't use a modal. The only way around it is to say "Please arrive early so that we are able to start our meeting on time".